# Postgresql: update from select always failed

Tags: postgresql

Please help,

I will update value in **account_move_line** (column tax_number) with value in **account_invoice_line** (column no_pajak).
But it always return **Null**.

This is my code :

```
update account_move_line aml set tax_number =  (
   select no_pajak as tax_number from account_invoice_line 
   where invoice_id = aml.invoice_id and no_pajak is not NULL  
)  
where tax_number is NULL and date > '2017-08-01'
```

Thank you very much

Comment: the code should work. please provide sample data in the table and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use lateral join this way, so rewrote it with CTE:

```
with u as (
   select no_pajak, invoice_id id
   from account_invoice_line 
   join account_move_line aml on invoice_id = aml.invoice_id and no_pajak is not NULL   
)
update account_move_line aml set tax_number =  no_pajak
from u 
where invoice_id = id
and tax_number is NULL and date > '2017-08-01'
```

should work, although seems overcomplicated